# add an object in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have the following Structs:

```
struct Photo{
    char name[30];          
};

struct List {
    Element *data;
    int count;
    int capacity;
};
```

and `typedef Photo* Element;`

Also, I have an array of type "List": `List *list = new List[100];` and an element of type "Photo": `Photo *e = new Photo;`

I want to insert the element "*e" in the beginning of the array list. I'm using the following C++ statement: 
`list -> data[0] = e;`

but, I ended up with the `Segmentation fault: 11` error.

I'm new in C++ and I need to know how I can save the element "e" in the beginning of the array "list"

Comment: [use std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector`?

Comment: `std::vector<Photo>` probably use a `std::string` for name too.

Comment: Also, is it your intention for `data` being of type `Photo**` (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to a Photo object)?

Answer (score 4):

`list -> data[0] = e;` is not defined.

What you probably intended to do was `list[0].data = e;`

Comment: Corrected. Would like to point out that a std::vector or std::list would probably be a less error-prone solution. But then again, only you know that the program is suppoes to do in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I do not code in C++, but if I understood, you're trying to add a Photo to an array of List. You have to add List only to your List array.